# Trouble getting cssText property of JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on an HTML editor. I'm getting the clicked object like this:

```
$('#image').click(function(event) {
    recentSelection = $(this);
}
```

Then I'm saving modified object's clone to an array:

```
historyStack.push(recentSelection.clone());
```

My goal is to read the saved object's CSS. When I'm printing the whole object to the console, I can see `style` property, and within it, I can see `cssText` property, which is exactly what I'm looking for. But when I try to get it like this:

```
historyObject.style.cssText
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cssText' of undefined
```

Could you please guide me how can I achieve what I've described above? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.style` is a property of DOM element, not JQuery object:

```
$('#image')[0].style.cssText  // [0] returns actual DOM element for you
```

Please note that you might have more then 1 element, then you need to actually traverse through collection.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for :)